# Trying to install LMMS but get the error "Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?"

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt, lmms

I'm running Linux mint Xfce and trying to install LMMS using `sudo apt install lmms` but I get this error:

```
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/winehq-staging_6.17~focal-1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (1932 != 1928). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 199.232.66.217 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:dbd4301fc46570f00731408ddeac02561977ae5ab8b08d8f5f3c2c6852818dddeec717d8f67f4da21f2507ed51da661a73d70dac7a1a2e0a5dc02f3b74278dda
    - SHA256:b0aed899399d66fc5a2c37ddc670f305e0ca148041055f03c5f56df3f23c55b7
    - SHA1:9197ca14a5691dbf764eb40f86a63258aa998dc7 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:7847b322ca146f4da687d7e1fbe85d10 [weak]
    - Filesize:1928 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/wine-staging_6.17~focal-1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (3623076 != 3620848). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 199.232.66.217 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:6abbdc0fbccc1720f2d286c0c9f60fbb056fe2bba649fded660f6cceff13058bf33b421e1c417ac9500bd78bb5b2bb48842ea9a7829e11bd1cae2c6365299b88
    - SHA256:3394091590d2e143c1e4769b91966214d80360a126b4096bee53e6c0e9e09a1c
    - SHA1:7d6d24f31a331445e201e0edf4f5df1d740fd026 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:6b5039ef73e5cb968108199ff69fbbe5 [weak]
    - Filesize:3620848 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-i386/wine-staging-i386_6.17~focal-1_i386.deb  File has unexpected size (81675616 != 81686648). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 199.232.66.217 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:15ecee1d18684bfe81eeff78c260a94d4246b00f49d671df75a45ca5ef1372d17357587c751638f7a4e66a0757681046ea800d647d75477c528d1ce09714f632
    - SHA256:f9ba3563fbe79c652bdeabab9db7bca085741c80ef92ba770c7bc8b91b7c2964
    - SHA1:8d3071e2f05b1c05a53594179d2a985eecb9ae69 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:0b24400a2cda869352297f32ba395745 [weak]
    - Filesize:81686648 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/wine-staging-amd64_6.17~focal-1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (85280536 != 85266380). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 199.232.66.217 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:2004e42ecc066120ace39ddb2f0c89556eca37170e9d29cbabb98c8607ff38d9110ca144a32143220f7b3f7930919218c5f95b722dfd2c1b659654cf4345ebf7
    - SHA256:9d4c8a8fa45107023dcf395c7c0b32da3015671ab59b6a22d2a26a266235d3de
    - SHA1:c6062245aa568957b5ec8c601bb434ce1411df3c [weak]
    - MD5Sum:6bfc8126094d932d00ef56e8a6b02068 [weak]
    - Filesize:85266380 [weak]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

So far I've tried:

```
apt-get clean
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
apt-get clean
apt-get update 
apt-get upgrade
```

It might also be worth mentioning that there have been 4 packages that have been just refusing to upgrade. After running `apt list --upgradable` these are the 4 packages that seem to be giving me problems:

```
wine-staging-amd64/focal 6.17~focal-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.16~focal-1]
wine-staging-i386/focal 6.17~focal-1 i386 [upgradable from: 6.16~focal-1]
wine-staging/focal 6.17~focal-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.16~focal-1]
winehq-staging/focal 6.17~focal-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.16~focal-1]
```

I'm not sure what to do about this anymore. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO). Although many users here a very knowledgeable and could help, this is out of scope for this site. We concentrate on programming questions. For such questions, other linux and or network administration sites would be more suited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do. Have a look at the complete error text. It says:

"... File has unexpected size (1932 != 1928). Mirror sync in progress? ..."

The actual file size differs from the actual named file size. It may be that the mirror servers are being updated and therefore the file data is not correct.

Until this is fixed you won't be able to do anything. By the way, it is the same for me.

Comment: In the meantime, the package data has probably been corrected. I had, as already mentioned, the same problem. But just now the update went through without this error.